perf stat output difference with and without -e option
root@8ccbd6ec81f8:\~/my-bcc-image/cpusnoop# perf stat -e instructions ./a.out

Performance counter stats for './a.out':

          48100736      instructions                                                
    
       0.617569441 seconds time elapsed
    
       0.017860000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys

root@8ccbd6ec81f8:\~/my-bcc-image/cpusnoop# perf stat ./a.out

Performance counter stats for './a.out':

             20.91 msec task-clock                #    0.033 CPUs utilized          
             10000      context-switches          #  478.230 K/sec                  
                 1      cpu-migrations            #   47.823 /sec                   
                45      page-faults               #    2.152 K/sec                  
          41251447      cycles                    #    1.973 GHz                    
          69558790      instructions              #    1.69  insn per cycle         
          14950981      branches                  #  715.000 M/sec                  
            117103      branch-misses             #    0.78% of all branches        
         206185235      slots                     #    9.860 G/sec                  
          39402564      topdown-retiring          #     17.9% retiring              
          76005537      topdown-bad-spec          #     34.6% bad speculation       
          83453524      topdown-fe-bound          #     38.0% frontend bound        
          20700249      topdown-be-bound          #      9.4% backend bound         
    
       0.631733899 seconds time elapsed
    
       0.000000000 seconds user
       0.030711000 seconds sys

I ran perf once with the -e option specifically filtering the instruction count and once without the -e option taking all the readings.
The instruction count in these case varies very much. Can anyone explain the difference between the two cases. I am specifically looking insight into how perf works and actually gathers this info like when exactly it reads the performance counters
The source code for a.out
int main()
{
    unsigned int j = (unsigned int)1000000;
    unsigned int a = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < j; i++) 
    {
        a++;
    }
}

Compiled with gcc -O0

You didn't use --all-user or instructions:u so its counting kernel code in interrupt and system-call handlers as well.  That seems like a surprisingly large difference, though, unless your system was very busy with I/O or something.  The default instructions event should count the same as -e instructions or -e instructions,cycles,task-clock,... if the workload is the same, and counting user-space only can make that happen.

What hardware are you testing on, in case that matters?  Also, I notice your test only runs for 20ms.  So startup overhead (which involves a significant number of system calls by the dynamic linker) might run different numbers of instructions depending on OS cache hit or miss for path lookups or other things.  So maybe kernel instructions could account for the difference.

The hardware is x86_64

Ok but what CPU, like Skylake, Zen 4, Tremont atom?  Those all have different PMU hardware.

11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7
